# Print columns of data that wrap internally

Tags: bash, printf

I am printing some monitoring data from a log as such:

`printf "    %10s %5s  %25s    %15s   %15s  %s${txtrst}\n" $date $time $metric $status $current_criticality "$failure"`

I would like the last column, which does not have a defined length to wrap within its boundaries, of which the left-side is clearly defined and the right-side is wherever the screen is (normal wrapping location).  I have attempted to define the length, but that did not resolve it.

Example of the current output:

```
09/30/2015 14:39         execution        (SUCCESS)           SUCCESS
09/30/2015 14:34         execution         (FAILED)             ERROR  Step 3: Match Failed Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
09/30/2015 14:34         execution         (FAILED)           SUCCESS  Step 1: Match Failed Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
09/30/2015 14:34        round_trip         (10.174)             ERROR  Step 1: Match Failed Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
09/30/2015 14:34        round_trip         (10.174)           SUCCESS  Step 1: Match Failed Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
09/30/2015 13:30        round_trip         (94.652)             ERROR
09/30/2015 13:30        round_trip         (94.652)           SUCCESS
09/30/2015 13:19        round_trip          (0.257)           SUCCESS
09/30/2015 13:16        round_trip        (110.012)             ERROR
09/30/2015 13:16        round_trip        (110.012)           SUCCESS
```

I would love to see:

```
09/30/2015 14:39          execution       (SUCCESS)           SUCCESS
09/30/2015 14:34          execution        (FAILED)             ERROR  Step 3: Match Failed 
                                                                       Blah blah blah blah 
                                                                       blah blah blah.
09/30/2015 14:34          execution        (FAILED)           SUCCESS  Step 1: Match Failed 
                                                                       Blah blah blah blah 
                                                                       blah blah blah.
09/30/2015 14:34         round_trip        (10.174)             ERROR  Step 1: Match Failed 
                                                                       Blah blah blah blah 
                                                                       blah blah blah.
09/30/2015 14:34         round_trip        (10.174)           SUCCESS  Step 1: Match Failed 
                                                                       Blah blah blah blah    
                                                                       blah blah blah.
09/30/2015 13:30         round_trip        (94.652)             ERROR
09/30/2015 13:30         round_trip        (94.652)           SUCCESS
09/30/2015 13:19         round_trip         (0.257)           SUCCESS
09/30/2015 13:16         round_trip       (110.012)             ERROR
09/30/2015 13:16         round_trip       (110.012)           SUCCESS
```

much like a report from SQL*PLUS's formatting of columns: col $column format a15

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Welcome to U&L ! What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Archemar You ask that as if there were some simple way to do this that OP just needs to improve a little—but personally at least, I can't think of any easy way without resorting to, e.g., `perl`. Maybe `troff`/`tbl` can do it, but that's pretty obscure. I mean, I could come up with a kluge that works only because its the last column that wraps...

Comment: You have to check size of last arg, strip it, echo many white and next chunk, strip again, until under proper size. I agree with @derobert this require a bit of `awk/perl` or even `sed` programming.

Comment: @Archemar you know, this isn't [so]. Non-programmers are welcome here—so the OP isn't expected to be able to implement a word-wrap (or any other) algorithm in a programming language.

Comment: I mentioned setting the printf numeric, but also dabbled with column and could not find a suggested wrap command.  Also forgot to mention, this has just been using bash, but could use Perl or the sed, awk commands.

Comment: @Archemar Was hoping I wouldn't have to do a character count and loop, but if that is the only way to do a hanging indent or strict column, I'll do it.

Comment: I don't have a total solution for you, but here's a possible start: echo $failure | fmt -w $C | sed 's/^/                   /' where $C is a number you compute from $((COLUMNS - some_number)) and the spaces in the sed replacement are enough to push it over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a kluge that works only because it's the last column:

1. `printf` the first part of the line (all of it except `$failure`, including the spacing), *without* the trailing new line.
2. `echo "$failure" | fold -s -w $desired_width | sed -e "2,\$s/^/$spacing/"`

Where `$desired_width` is the width of the `$failure` column and $spacing is a lot of spaces to make the second line (third, etc.) start in the right spot. You could generate those spaces easily with something like `spacing=$(echo $'\t' | pr -Te71)`. The 71 should work, if I counted right...

This works by having `fold` perform a line wrap, then `sed` adds spacing (for alignment) to the second and subsequent columns. When printed, the first line will join with the other output (due to the lack of newline).

If I wanted to do this the right way, Perl has several modules (e.g., [`Text::ASCIITable`](http://p3rl.org/Text::ASCIITable), [`Text::SimpleTable`](http://p3rl.org/Text::SimpleTable), [`Text::TabularDisplay`](http://p3rl.org/Text::TabularDisplay) which should be able to do this.

Comment: Just testing with junk, that looks like it should do it!  Thanks for your expertise!

Comment: Is $s suppose to be set for something?  I get a sed error when the double quote attempts to evaluate the variable.  If I use single quotes, the spacing variable fails.  I know some on sed, but don't know exactly what is going on with the first section.  Does chopping the 2,$  produce the same results?

Comment: @krmarshall87 Oh! Sorry, I failed to escape that $... It's not a shell variable, it's part of the sed syntax. (Fixed). I was originally testing with the spacing inline, and using single quotes...

Answer (score 1):

There's probably something that already exists, but ...

```
awk -v cols=$(tput cols) '
    NR == 1 {
        prefix = gensub(/^(([[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]+){5}).*/, "\\\\1", 1, $0)
        prefix_width = length(prefix) + 2
        diff = cols - prefix_width
    }
    NF == 5 { print; next }
    {
        prefix = substr($0, 0, prefix_width)
        text = substr($0, prefix_width+1)
        while (length(text) > diff) {
            for (i=diff; i>0; i--) {
                char = substr(text,i,1)
                if (char == " " || char == "-") break
            }
            if (i == 0) i = diff  # no spaces or hyphens, break mid-word
            printf "%*s%s\n", prefix_width, prefix, substr(text,0,i);
            text = substr(text,i+1)
            prefix = ""
        }
        if (text) printf "%*s%s\n", prefix_width, prefix, text
    }
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The rough way is to after reformatting like

```
indent='                                                                      '
sed "s/.\{$((${#indent}+2)),$COLUMNS\} /&\n$indent /;P;D"
```

(where `indent` is 70 spaces == 10 + 5 + 25 + 15 + 15 from `printf` command)
But the pre-formatting is better:

```
indent='                                                                      '
mapfile failure < <(fold -s -w $(($COLUMNS-${#indent}-1)) <<<"$failure")
printf "%10s%5s%25s%15s%15s" $date $time $metric $status $current_criticality
printf " %b$indent" "${failure[@]}\c"
```